# I thought this was a good question: Certifications required to become a PM

Tags: discussion, questions

I know it polls and there are no unequovical, definitive answers; however, it seems to me that there would be value to hear the opinions of various practitioners: pros, cons, what we do know about them in terms of hiring filters or performance indicators, etc.  Thoughts?

Comment: Ok David, I still think we need more details from the asker, but let's try your experiment with the modified question:  http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/are-certifications-important-to-becoming-a-pm. I'll reopen, but feel free to edit further if we can make it better.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/are-certifications-important-to-becoming-a-pm) could be valuable. But right now, he's pretty much asking for a list of people who know project managers with/without certifications. As it stands, it's not valuable... but like you said... it could be!

I was hoping the asker would come back and maybe be a little more clear about asking for definitive answers. However, I see that's sort of tough to do because of the nature of the question.

I'm off work now and will spend a little editing time to see if I can push it back over the line of constructiveness. Feel free to jump into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/project-management) if you're around and we can maybe figure it out together.

As a community, we're still trying to figure out what's best for our site. If we can do *anything* to improve questions at this point, even if it doesn't make them perfect, that to me seems like a good enough justification to reopen them, if nothing else but to have more data to look at during evals.

**Would it help if I indicated in the comments on closed questions that I think other editors could possibly help salvage the question? Would this help encourage more community editing?**

I'm going to change the question a bit and try to guess what he's really after. Without the asker in this case, all we can really do is hope we preserve the spirit of the question.